# How to remove utf-8, unix from vi editor

Tags: linux, vim, vi

In my vi editor, at last I'm getting this line

```
~
~ 1 sample.tf [tf,utf-8,unix]                                       0x0 10,1 All
```

sample.tf is my file name.
Due to this I'm facing indentation issue. Whenever I'm pasting something in the file its look like this.

```
cluster_id = "xxxx-xxx" 
     engine = "redis"
          node_type = "cache.t2.medium" 
             num_cache_nodes = 1 
                 parameter_group_name = "default.redis5.0.cluster.on"
```

Comment: Better suited for [Vi and Vim](https://vi.stackexchange.com/). And you need to write your question more clearly, because for now, I think the information you provided so far isn't related to each other at all.

Comment: this two things have most likely nothing in common, also I strongly suspect you are using `vim` and not `vi` right?

Comment: An example of [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/812128). Those things are completely unrelated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have `indent` mode or `auto indent` or sth... . 
To turn off autoindent when you paste code use `paste mode` in `INSERT MODE`:

```
:set paste
```

and for disable :

```
:set nopaste
```

or `toggle` :

```
set pastetoggle
```

then paste it.